# Showing that $\lim_{z\to0}z\,\frac{\cos(z/2)}{\sin(z/2)}=2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Here is an integration using residue thm that I want to understand the final answer of it:

> [image]

I do not understand why
$$\lim_{z\to0}z\,\frac{\cos(z/2)}{\sin(z/2)}=2$$
Could someone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the well-known fact that $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\sin z}{z} = 1$$
Then
$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{\sin z} = 1$$
as well.
So
$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z/2}{\sin z/2} = 1$$
and therefore
$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{\sin z/2} = 2$$

Finally, combine this with the fact that $\lim_{z\to 0} \cos(z/2) = \cos 0 = 1$ to get
$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z \cos(z/2)}{\sin (z/2)} = 2$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z\cos(z/2)}{\sin(z/2)}=\lim_{z \to 0}\cos(z/2) \times \lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z}{\sin(z/2)}\stackrel{L'H}{=}1\times\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}\cos(z/2)}=2  $$

Comment: How did you use L'Hospital?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dz} z =1$ and $\frac{d}{dz}\sin(z/2) =\frac{1}{2}\cos(z/2)$

Answer (score 0):

When $x$ is close to zero, $\cos x$ is approximately $1$, and $\sin x$ is approximately $x$.

So for small $z$, $$z\frac{\cos (z/2)}{\sin(z/2)}$$ is approximately $$z\frac1{z/2}=2.$$

Alternatively, use L'Hospital's rule.